# How to avoid character escaping in codeigniter active recoreds "where" clause and Join clause

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I am trying to join 2 tables with "IF" condition in one part of Join. But where I passed it to $this->db->join, it adding a escape around IF. how can I avoid this?

Comment: Is it possible to rewrite your query to do that `if` logic in the `where`. CodeIgnitor's `->where()` has an optional third parameter you can set to `false` to keep it from tossing backticks around things. (I'm guessing it's backticks that you are seeing, right?)

Comment: Yes its backtick. But its not with where. Its with join

Comment: I understand it's not with `WHERE`, but there is no escape toggle flag in `JOIN` in codeigniter. Often times though a query with a `CASE` or `IF` in in the `JOIN` can be rewritten with an extra join to the same table and an `IF` in either the `SELECT` or `WHERE` depending on your needs. My recommendation would be to rewrite the query so you can make use of the escape toggle flags on `SELECT` or `WHERE`. The real question here is why doesn't codeigniter have that damned parameter on `JOIN`. Crazy bananas there.